# Split/extract strings in Pandas series index and expand as DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Pandas series as below:

```
index      Value
'4-5-a'     2
'6-7-d'     3
'9-6-c'     7
'5-3-k'     8
```

I would like to extract/split the index of the series and form a DataFrame as shown below:

```
index      Value   x    y
'4-5-a'     2      4    5
'6-7-d'     3      6    7
'9-6-c'     7      9    6
'5-3-k'     8      5    3
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
# convert series to dataframe, elevate index to column
df = s.to_frame('Value').reset_index()

# split by dash and exclude final split
df[['x', 'y']] = df['index'].str.split('-', expand=True).iloc[:, :-1].astype(int)

print(df)

   index  Value  x  y
0  4-5-a      2  4  5
1  6-7-d      3  6  7
2  9-6-c      7  9  6
3  5-3-k      8  5  3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is that the original data is not DF but a series. So the index is the index of the series.